# Unicode-math does not render the Gamma letter

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

(updated)

I wonder why `unicode-math` does not render the letter Latin Gamma!?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
$ɣ γ$
\end{document}
```

This only render the Greek Gamma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character you're using is

> ɣ U+0263 LATIN SMALL LETTER GAMMA

while the character you want is

> γ U+03B3 GREEK SMALL LETTER GAMMA

They're different and should not be confused with each other.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_gamma for some information about U+0263.

Comment: Thanks, What about inserting the Latin Gamma? Even setting math font to Tahoma does not print the letter. Do you mean the unicode-math can render a subset of the Unicode glyphs.

Comment: @PHPst I don't understand; with `unicode-math`, the Greek gamma is interpreted as a math character (in math mode), because this has always been customary; there's no reason for using the Latin gamma in that sense.